# AWS Authorize Ingress for a specific Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to create a user that is enabled to change a specific security group (e.g. `mySecurityGroup`). The user should be able to open and close a port on the security group. Now I have problems to restrict the user to only one security group. Is there any way I can the the following policy that it is only valid for `mySecurityGroup`

```
{
"Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "Stmt1349420732465",
    "Action": [
      "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
      "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
    "*"
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. As the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_SpecificProducts.html) states IAM doesn't support any resources for EC2.